# Wininet FTP get server responses at runtime

Tags: ftp, wininet

I use wininet to connect to ftp server, i see that wininet only gives true:false for each command that is used to communicate with the server and the classic GetLastError() to get the specific error if any.

What i cant find with wininet is how to get responses from the ftp server whithout sending commands like a stand by mode, i cant find the way if the server choose to disconect me or timeout my session how to get back that response from the ftp server so i can know what is going on with the connection and do the appropiate actions after each response.

Anyone knows ?